# update data in observable angular 9

Tags: angular, observable, fetch, behaviorsubject

I have problem when add a user the Html table does not refresh how can i make it with observable ?, I have *`register`* method in **`AccountService`** and *`getAllAdmins`* in **`UsersService`**, and in admins List component fetch the data after subscribe on *`getAllAdmins`* method

**UsersService**

```
export class UsersService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  HTTP_URL = environment.HTTP_URL;

  getAllAdmins(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.HTTP_URL + 'UserProfile/GetAdmins'));
  }
```

**AccountService**

```
export class AccountService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  HTTP_URL = environment.HTTP_URL;

  register(reg: RegisterModel): Observable<RegisterModel> {
    return this.http.post<RegisterModel>(this.HTTP_URL + 'ApplicationUser/Register' , reg).pipe();
  }
```

**This function From `AdminsListComponent.ts`**

```
getAdmins() {
    this.usersService.getAllAdmins().subscribe(list => {
      this.admins = list;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to implement the logic to reload the users when one is added

Comment: how ? did you mean in ngOnInit recall the method getAdmins ?

Comment: No, whenever that register method is called you need to somehow call getAllAdmins again. How exactly you accomplish this depends on how your app is set up and your needs